# How to serialize/deserialize ggplot object for use with mongodb in R

Tags: r, mongodb, serialization, ggplot2

I have this code:

```
for(plot in plotResults) {
  .session$plots[[plot$id]] <- if (!is.null(plot[["grob"]])) {
    plot[["grob"]]
  } else {
    plot[["plot"]]
  }
  ggsave(paste0(plot$id, ".png"), .session$plots[[plot$id]])
  ...
```

}

the file get generated but when I save the ggplot object to mongo using this tools:

```
serializeObj <- function(obj) {
  if (is.list(obj)) {
    structure(lapply(obj, serializeObj), names = serializeNames(obj))
  } else {
    rawToChar(serialize(obj, NULL, ascii = TRUE))
  }
}

deserializeObj <- function(obj) {
  if (is.list(obj)) {
    structure(lapply(obj, deserializeObj), names = unserializeNames(obj))
  } else if (is.serialized(obj)) {
    unserialize(charToRaw(obj))
  } else {
    obj
  }
}

## Replaces characters illegal in Mongo names with "safe" substitutes
safeNames <- function(value) {
  gsub("\\.", "___DOT___", value)
}

## Replaces back "safe" substitutes
unsafeNames <- function(value) {
  gsub("___DOT___", ".", value)
}

serializeNames <- function(obj) {
  lapply(names(obj), safeNames)
}

unserializeNames <- function(obj) {
  lapply(names(obj), unsafeNames)  
}
```

I'm running serializeObj before I save to mongo and then later deserializeObj after read from mongo. And after read instead of ggplot object I've got list and I can't call ggsave on that list.

How can I serialize object of some type like ggplot and then deserialize it to get the same object?

Comment: A ggplot is a (nested) list. Use `str` to check that. Your approach loses attributes, most importantly the class attributes.

Comment: @Roland is there a way to restore the class attribute?

Comment: `help("attr")`, `help("attributes")`, of course you need to store them first. Otherwise, we are talking about manual work for some of the sublists' attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work, instead of recursive serializer/deserializer only one level is needed and also no need to serialize names because they don't have dots anymore only nested plot data had them.

```
serializePlots <- function(data) {
  lapply(data, function(plot) {
    rawToChar(serialize(plot, NULL, ascii = TRUE))
  })
}

unserializePlots <- function(data) {
  lapply(data, function(obj) {
    if (is.serialized(obj)) {
      unserialize(charToRaw(obj))
    } else {
      obj
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As pointed in your comments, you are losing information about the classes of the ggplot object. You should probably make sure to store this information and recover it when you unserialize. For example, I wrote three simple f(x) that may help.

```
#### custom f(x)    
serializeGGClasses <- function(obj) {
  serializeObj(sapply(obj, class))
}

unserializeGGClasses <- function(obj) {
  lapply(obj, (function(el) {unserialize(charToRaw(el)) } ))
}

restoreGGClasses <- function(plot.obj, class.obj) {
  class(plot.obj) <- c("gg", "ggplot")
  for (i in 1:length(plot.obj)) {
   class(plot.obj[[i]]) <- class.obj[[i]] 
  }
  return(plot.obj)
}

###
```

Now, you could serialize all classes of the ggplot object and store them in your db. When you retrive the object, you need to restore them

```
library(ggplot2)    
a<- qplot(1, 1)
class(a)     # "gg"     "ggplot"
is.list(a)   # TRUE

b <-  serializeObj(a)
b.class <- serializeGGClasses(a)

# Unserialize
c <- deserializeObj(b)
c.class <- unserializeGGClasses(b.class)

# Right now, "c" is just a list
final.c <- restoreGGClasses(plot.obj = c, 
                            class.obj = c.class)

# "final.c" can be plotted
final.c
```

Comment: unfortunately this don't work, the plot was messed up after deserialization. Recursive approach was wrong.